# Extracting value under particular column in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

My string is like below

```
Module   Available     Used     Remaining
          (Watts)     (Watts)    (Watts) 
------   ---------   --------   ---------
1           485.0        0.0       485.0
```

I need to extract value under `Used`. I was trying to split the string. Is there any better way to get the value?

Comment: Maybe there is something helpful here: [Extract a column from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964942/extract-a-column-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.split`

**demo:**

```
s = """Module   Available     Used     Remaining
          (Watts)     (Watts)    (Watts) 
------   ---------   --------   ---------
1           485.0        0.0       485.0"""

for i in s.split("\n"):
    if i.strip()[0].isdigit():
        val = i.split()
        print(val[2])
```

**Using regex:**

```
import re
val = re.findall("\d+\s+\d*\s+\d*\.\d*\s+\d*\.\d*\s+\d*\.\d*", s)
for v in val:
    print(v.split()[2])
```

**Output:**

```
0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one is an overkill, but you can use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) to read a string in a dataframe and then get the desired value:

```
import io

import pandas as pd

your_string = io.StringIO("""Module   Available     Used     Remaining
          (Watts)     (Watts)    (Watts) 
------   ---------   --------   ---------
1           485.0        0.0       485.0""")

df = pd.read_csv(your_string, 
                 sep=" ", 
                 skipinitialspace=True, 
                 skiprows=[1, 2])
```

`df` will look like this:

```
    Module  Available   Used    Remaining
0   1   485.0   0.0     485.0
```

And

```
print(df.loc[0, 'Used'])
```

will give your `0.0`.

**P.S.:** This was based on [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22605281/7851470) answer for the question "How to create a Pandas DataFrame from a string".